# How to upvote a photo and automatically downvote the other photo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a show view for a contests model that displays 2 random photos:

```
<% if @contest.photos.size < 2 %>
    <p>not enough photos in this contest</p>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag @random_photo1.image.url(:thumb)), upvote_path(id: @contest.id, photo_id: @random_photo1.id) %>
    <%= @random_photo1.score %>
    <%= link_to (image_tag @random_photo2.image.url(:thumb)), "#" %>
    <%= @random_photo2.score %>
<% end %>
```

here's my show action:

```
  def show
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:id])
    @user = current_user

    random_two_photos = @contest.photos.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
    @random_photo1 = random_two_photos[0]
    @random_photo2 = random_two_photos[1]
  end
```

Here're my routes for the 2 actions:

```
  get 'contest/:id/photo/:photo_id' => 'contests#enter_contest', as: :enter_contest
  get 'contest/:id/photo/:photo_id' => 'contests#upvote', as: :upvote
```

How do I write my "upvote" controller action so that the photo I click on gets 100 points while the other one gets -100 points? I'm using postgresql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another routes:

```
get 'contests/:id/start' => 'contests#start', as: start_contest
put 'contests/:id/vote' => 'contests#vote', as: vote
```

Then, in **contests_controller/start** action

```
def start
  @contest = Contest.find(params[:id])
  random_photos = @contest.photos.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
  @photo1 = random_photos.first
  @photo2 = random_photos.last
end
```

In **contests_controller/start** action

```
def vote
  @contest = Contest.find(params[:id])
  @photo1 = Photo.find(params[:up_photo_id])
  @photo2 = Photo.find(params[:down_photo_id])
  @photo1.upvote # you need to put this method in Photo model
  @photo2.downvote # you need to put this method in the Photo model
end
```

In **contests/start** view:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@photo1.image.url(:thumb)), vote_path(id: @contest.id, up_photo_id: @photo1.id, down_photo_id: @photo2.id) %>
```

and...

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@photo2.image.url(:thumb)), vote_path(id: @contest.id, up_photo_id: @photo2.id, down_photo_id: @photo1.id) %>
```

> Remember: you need to pass the option `method: :put` to [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) helper in order to perform a PUT instead a GET.

**Improvements**

- You can put the code inside **vote** action inside a [Transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html). It's not a clean solution to put transactions in the controller layer. Maybe you can use the [Service pattern](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services)
- You can move the "links to" method to a view helper. Something like: `vote_link(contest, up_photo, down_photo)`to avoid code repetition.
- You can move this: `photos.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")` to a method into the model. Something like: `@contest.random_photos(2)`

> The code I wrote was not tested. But you get the idea...

**UPDATE TO USE A SINGLE SHOW ACTION**

You need to define a single route

```
resources :contests, only: [:show]
```

Then in  **contests_controller/show** action

```
def show
  @contest = Contest.find(params[:id])

  if params.has_key? :up_photo_id && params.has_key? :down_photo_id
    @photo1 = Photo.find(params[:up_photo_id])
    @photo2 = Photo.find(params[:down_photo_id])
    @photo1.upvote # you need to put this method in Photo model
    @photo2.downvote # you need to put this method in the Photo model
  else 
    random_photos = @contest.photos.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")
    @photo1 = random_photos.first
    @photo2 = random_photos.last
  end
end
```

In **show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@photo1.image.url(:thumb)), contest_path(id: @contest.id, up_photo_id: @photo1.id, down_photo_id: @photo2.id) %>
```

and...

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@photo2.image.url(:thumb)), contest_path(id: @contest.id, up_photo_id: @photo2.id, down_photo_id: @photo1.id) %>
```

**UPDATE: to get different photos**

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base

  def random_photos
    self.photos.order("RANDOM()")
  end

  def two_different_photos
    photo1 = random_photos.first
    raise 'no photos' unless photo1 # raise an exception or something
    photo2 = random_photos.where.not(id: photo1.id).first
    raise 'only one photo' unless photo2 # raise an exception or something
    [photo1, photo2]
  end
end
```

then you can use `@contest.two_different_photos` in your controller...

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try this right now. Just curious, what's your brief opinion on rails vs mean stack?

Comment: Wait, I'm a bit confused. Currently, the two random photos are being shown through the contests#show controller action. If I write the contests#start action, wouldn't it affect two random photos that're not the ones intended?

Comment: About mean... I have no experience with express or node, mongo a little bit and I have experience with angular. But still, I'm more a backend/ruby guy. So, I have no a "useful" opinion. Your second question: you can use the show action instead the start action if you want. If the "starts action" represents the contest, use show. What you mean with this: "the contests#start action, wouldn't it affect two random photos that're not the ones intended"?

Comment: On start action you will get the random pictures. After click on vote (for pic 1 or 2) you will go to vote action with the photo ids. After vote, you can show in the vote view the photos with the new score (or something). Is that what you want? If you want to reuse the start view you can use a partial and share between start and vote views.

Comment: Thanks. I have contests_controller/show representing the contest instead of start. When I click an image, it prompts "Missing template contests/vote". I just want to be able to click one photo, have the scores change, and two new random photos show up on the same show page without having to redirect. Wish this was as simple as an onClick()

Comment: The error it's because `your_app/app/views/contests/vote.html.erb` is not defined... Why you not want to use a redirect? after `@photo2.downvote` you need to do `redirect_to :action => "start", :id => XXX` (or show instead start) if you want to get 2 new photos. If you don't want to do that. You need the show view only and ask something like params.has_key? : up_photo_id && params.has_key? : down_photo_id  to know if you want 2 new random photos or vote. I think it's a little bit dirty

Comment: I wouldn't use the normal show view to represent a "specific state" of contest. If in the future you want to see a contest resource without the vote functionality what you gonna to do?

Comment: Thanks so much for all your suggestions. I followed your advice and moved the voting to a contests/start.html.erb view. Now one problem that wasn't there before is that sometimes photo1 and photo2 are the same photo.
Two other things I'm trying to implement (you don't have to help me with this)
1. when photo1 gets upvote, new score is (photo1.score+photo2.score+400)/photo1.vote_counter
2. photo1 is selected at random, but photo2 is a random photo that is +/- 400 score compared to photo1. I'm thinking I should use a .where method?

Comment: For the first problem I did this but it can't find params:

  def upvote
   self.vote_counter += 1
    self.score = (self.score + Photo.find(params[:down_photo_id]).score + 400)/self.vote_counter
    self.save
  end

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you with your first question. I did not understand the second one. I think you need to create another question for that issue.